# What is this error in volley connection ==> Unable to resolve host "[REDACTED_DOMAIN_NAME]": No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, android-volley

I received more than 1000 errors in the ّ`Firebase`

> **Errors:**
>
> 1- NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
>
> 2- Unable to resolve host "[REDACTED_DOMAIN_NAME]": No address
>   associated with hostname
>
> 3- failed to connect to [REDACTED_DOMAIN_NAME]/185.94.97.54 (port 80)
>   after 10000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
>
> 4- recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

All of these errors are related to the volley library.

Most users use the app without problems, and this error only occurs on some devices.

My app permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

I will review these permission at the time of submitting the request by volley

I run the following code before I send it by volley:

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable(boolean showToast) {
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || 
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return false;
    }
    ConnectivityManager cM = (ConnectivityManager) G.context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    boolean isNetworkAvailable = cM.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cM.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected() && cM.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable();

    if(!isNetworkAvailable && showToast) {
        TastyToast.makeText(G.context, "error: " + "no network available!!!", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR).show();
    }
    return isNetworkAvailable;
}
```

Where is the problem and what should be done to resolve these errors?

Comment: poor network condition sometimes happens, e.g. users in remote regions with spotty cellular connections

Comment: Is not this a particular problem? And I can not do anything to solve it?